# Celery Periodic Task not working on given crontab params

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery, periodic-task

I need to perform some background tasks in Django at a particular time so I'm using `@periodic_task` in my `tasks.py` file.

Basically I have two tasks:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(day_of_month='3-11', hour=11, minute=32)), name="invoice_simulation", ignore_result=False)
def invoice_simulation():
    print('---- task started-----')
    # Do something


@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*')), name="print_time_worker", ignore_result=False)
def print_time():
    print('Current time is: ', datetime.now())
```

On my local, everything is running properly but when I push my code to the server then only `print_time()` works and `invoice_simulation` is not working on the server.

My code is deployed on `Heroku`

after deployment celery logs on server look like...

```
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648963+00:00 app[worker.1]:  
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648975+00:00 app[worker.1]:  -------------- celery@73b10f01-6293-42ad-a0f5-867e4b39f43d v3.1.18 (Cipater)
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648976+00:00 app[worker.1]: ---- **** ----- 
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648977+00:00 app[worker.1]: --- * ***  * -- Linux-3.13.0-133-generic-x86_64-with-debian-jessie-sid
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648977+00:00 app[worker.1]: -- * - **** --- 
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648978+00:00 app[worker.1]: - ** ---------- [config]
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648979+00:00 app[worker.1]: - ** ---------- .> app:         __main__:0x7f8608f52358
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648980+00:00 app[worker.1]: - ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://h:**@ec2-****.compute-1.amazonaws.com:17709//
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648981+00:00 app[worker.1]: - ** ---------- .> results:     redis://h:*@ec2-****.compute-1.amazonaws.com:17709
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648981+00:00 app[worker.1]: - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648982+00:00 app[worker.1]: -- ******* ---- 
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648983+00:00 app[worker.1]: --- ***** ----- [queues]
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648983+00:00 app[worker.1]:  -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648984+00:00 app[worker.1]:                 
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648984+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648985+00:00 app[worker.1]: [tasks]
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648986+00:00 app[worker.1]:   . djcelery_email_send_multiple
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648986+00:00 app[worker.1]:   . invoice_simulation
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648987+00:00 app[worker.1]:   . mdn_core_engine.celery.debug_task
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648987+00:00 app[worker.1]:   . print_time_worker
2018-01-03T11:30:06.648991+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2018-01-03T11:30:06.722749+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2018-01-03 11:30:06,722: INFO/Beat] beat: Starting...
2018-01-03T11:30:06.763365+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2018-01-03 11:30:06,751: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://h:**@ec2-****.compute-1.amazonaws.com:17709//
2018-01-03T11:30:06.832074+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2018-01-03 11:30:06,831: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
2018-01-03T11:30:07.859195+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2018-01-03 11:30:07,858: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
```

On heroku, worker config is:

```
 celery -A mdn_core_engine worker -B --loglevel=info
```

Comment: please share the command used to start celery.

Comment: @aliva updated my question